# Make root node in Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have an array of JSON in my Rails App in this format using Active Model Serializer:

```
[
  {
    "contact" : {}
  },
  {
    "contact" : {}
  }
]
```

How do I make it so that I remove one level of node above the contact USING active model serializer like this:

```
[
 {
 },
 {
 }
]
```

I also want to remove the node name "contact".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This was covered in [RailsCast #409 Active Model Serializers](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers).

In order to remove the root node, you add `root: false` in the call to `render` in your controller.  Assuming your `contact`s in JSON come from a `contacts#index` method, your code may look something like:

```
def index
  @contacts = Contacts.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @contacts, root: false }
  end
end
```

Or, if you don't want any root nodes in any of your JSON, in your `ApplicationController`, add the following method:

```
def default_serializer_options
  {root: false}
end
```

Comment: I actually do have that setup. I guess I didn't explain it correctly. The object has a list of attributes including the contact object and I have hidden all the other attributes. I just want the contact object to be the root.

Answer (score 15):

For people using ActiveModel::Serializer v0.10.x, you will need to create an initializer and include the following:

```
# config/initializers/serializer.rb
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
ActiveModelSerializers.config.json_include_toplevel_object = true
```

Then, just restart your app and you should get the root objects you desire.

This works in Rails 5.1.x.  YMMV.  HTH.

Answer (score 6):

> */config/initializers/serializer.rb*

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api # Default: `:attributes`
```

> By default ActiveModelSerializers will use the Attributes Adapter (**no
>   JSON root**). But we strongly advise you to use JsonApi Adapter, which
>   follows **1.0** of the format specified in jsonapi.org/format.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the root node has the name of your controller by default if I am not wrong.

```
format.json { render json: @contacts}
```

Of course you need to remove root false, it removes the node's name.

If you want contact as root object use this:

```
format.json { render json :@contacts, :root => 'contact' }
```